# SQL Statement With 'Totals' as Final Column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to run an SQL query with the first column being 'month'. Each column will have a number value (or the month number) and the final column will say 'Totals'. The issue is that when I try to have them order, it gives me errors every time it reaches the Totals column because it is looking for an INT value. So, for example, I have this query:

```
SELECT CY.Month, CY.PaymentAmount_ThisYear, LY.PaymentAmount_LastYear FROM
(SELECT DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate) AS Month, SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) as PaymentAmount_ThisYear 
    FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
    GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate)
) CY
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate) AS Month, SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) as PaymentAmount_LastYear
    FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -13, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
    GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate)
) LY
ON CY.Month = LY.Month
UNION
SELECT 'Totals' AS Month, CY.PaymentAmount_ThisYear, LY.PaymentAmount_LastYear FROM
(SELECT SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) AS PaymentAmount_ThisYear
    FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
) CY,
(SELECT SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) AS PaymentAmount_LastYear
    FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -13, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
) LY
```

If I changed 'Totals' to 13, it works and puts the totals at the bottom but the row says '13' instead of 'Totals'.

[image]

So what I then tried was at the very beginning of the query I changed this:

```
SELECT CY.Month
```

To

```
SELECT CAST(CY.Month AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Month
```

But when I do that it orders them wrong it goes:

```
1
10
11
5
```

Because it's recognizing them as varchar values. I'm basically looking for this to order the months numerically but then have the last column say 'Totals'.

I also tried to do an

ORDER BY
CASE ISNUMERIC(Month)
WHEN 1 THEN CAST(Month AS INT)
ELSE Month
END

But that was giving me an 'Ambiguous column name 'Month'.' error.

I'm sort of stuck, any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to have the last row be a total row? That sort of thing should be done with your display code or after you export it to a spreadsheet.

Comment: @TonyDeStefano, yes the issue is that we're doing from within the Volusion framework (ecommerce). The issue is that you have a window where you can do a SELECT query so it's not done through any sort of 'display code', it just does the query and outputs it in CSV format. The reason we want the totals on the end is that it's for a client and we just want it to work off a single click for them. It seems like it's possible and I've gotten super close with these different attempts...I feel like I'm just one small change off but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Can you left pad the one-digit months with a zero so it orders them like so: 01, 02, 03 ... 11, 12, Totals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your query considerably and use the ROLLUP option of GROUP BY to do your totals, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
      CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(MONTH(orders.orderdate)) = 1 
        THEN 'Totals' 
        ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(2), MONTH(orders.orderdate)) 
      END AS [Month]
    , SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN YEAR(orders.orderdate) = Datepart(yy, Dateadd(mm, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
            THEN orders.paymentamount 
            ELSE 0.00
        END
        )   AS PaymentAmount_ThisYear 
    , SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN YEAR(orders.orderdate) = Datepart(yy, Dateadd(mm, -13, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
            THEN orders.paymentamount 
            ELSE 0.00 
        END
        )   AS PaymentAmount_LastYear 
FROM   
    orders 
GROUP BY   
    MONTH(orders.orderdate)
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! I've a couple things to add to it so this is perfect to get this first part started. Definitely much cleaner than our way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the current query in an inline view and then ordering afterwards

```
SELECT Month, PaymentAmount_ThisYear, PaymentAmount_LastYear
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(CY.Month AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Month, CY.PaymentAmount_ThisYear, LY.PaymentAmount_LastYear FROM
        (SELECT DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate) AS Month, SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) as PaymentAmount_ThisYear 
            FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
            GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate)
        ) CY
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate) AS Month, SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) as PaymentAmount_LastYear
            FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -13, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
            GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, Orders.OrderDate)
        ) LY
    ON CY.Month = LY.Month
    UNION
    SELECT 'Totals' AS Month, CY.PaymentAmount_ThisYear, LY.PaymentAmount_LastYear FROM
        (SELECT SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) AS PaymentAmount_ThisYear
            FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        ) CY,
        (SELECT SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) AS PaymentAmount_LastYear
            FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(YY, Orders.OrderDate) = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -13, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        ) LY) T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Month) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Month
```