# Resetting the Cumulative Sum on a SUM Clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stumbling through some SQL and have a question about resetting a cumulative sum. I'm not sure if it's possible and other examples I've found are slightly different than mine. Another SO member helped me a ton with this solution to printing out the totals of some orders (it was a completely different approach than I had previously been trying; [SQL Statement With 'Totals' as Final Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905943/sql-statement-with-totals-as-final-column)). This is that solution with some new lines:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN GROUPING(MONTH(orders.orderdate)) = 1 
    THEN 'Totals' 
    ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(2), MONTH(orders.orderdate)) 
  END AS [Month]
, SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(orders.orderdate) = Datepart(yy, Dateadd(mm, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        THEN 
            CASE
                WHEN MONTH(orders.orderdate) = 01 or MONTH(orders.orderdate) = 02 or MONTH(orders.orderdate) = 03 or MONTH(orders.orderdate) = 04 MONTH(orders.orderdate) = 05
                THEN 1.54
                ELSE orders.total_payment_received
            END
        ELSE 0.00 
    END
    )   AS PaymentReceived_LastYear
, SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(orders.orderdate) = Datepart(yy, Dateadd(mm, -13, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        THEN orders.total_payment_received
        ELSE 0.00 
    END
    )   AS PaymentReceived_LastYear 
FROM   
    orders 
GROUP BY   
    MONTH(orders.orderdate)
WITH ROLLUP
```

The nested CASE statement is where I'm getting tripped. I basically want to get the values of all of these months except the values from January, February, March, April and May of this year. INSTEAD, I want to set those months to explicit values. In this case, I've set them all to 1.54 but I will update the value for all of those months once I can wrap my head around this. When I do this, though, it does (as expected) a thing where every time it sees one of those months, it adds 1.54 to the previous value for that month.

This is what I get when I run it (btw I fudged the numbers to not give live data; really you're just looking at the values for 1 and 5 under paymentreceived_lastyear:

```
month   paymentreceived_lastyear    paymentreceived_lastyear
1       620.62                      765707960.7
2       0                           16577632.06
3       0                           95678.83
4       0                           7657.26
5       340.34                      78768.77
6       15650809.66                 9787876.52
7       22865443.89                 1765153.61
8       27652860.86                 67584.48
9       15563227.11                 745.4
10      15650478.29                 74657765452.67
11      92757668.09                 65765438.12
12      38675157.93                 176519535.45
Totals  75727606.79                 1267508279.87
```

What that means is that 403 orders happened on the first month (403 * 1.54 equals 620.62; it's summing it; 221 for the fifth month by the same logic). By my code, I want it to be like this:

```
month   paymentreceived_lastyear    paymentreceived_lastyear
1       1.54                        765707960.7
2       0                           16577632.06
3       0                           95678.83
4       0                           7657.26
5       1.54                        78768.77
6       15650809.66                 9787876.52
7       22865443.89                 1765153.61
8       27652860.86                 67584.48
9       15563227.11                 745.4
10      15650478.29                 74657765452.67
11      92757668.09                 65765438.12
12      38675157.93                 176519535.45
Totals  75727606.79                 1267508279.87
```

I want it to just reset the cumulative sum for those values and show whatever value I set for those months (I will fill in the actual values later). Ideally, each month between 1 and 5 would have the ability to have their own static value.

I want to either reset the value in the SUM clause figuring if I reset it and then declare the variable, the last time through the 'loop' it will be resetting it and declaring it to the variable OR if I can just straight declare a static value to it that would be great as well.

Any ideas? I don't have access to the database entirely but for my purposes here I'm only working with orders.orderdate (a date value) and orders.total_payment_received which is a float value.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, just updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a start and end date for the Jan --> May group (2015-01-01 to 2015-06-01) and assign them to variables.

Then use those dates to partition out the items for summation, so your SUM statement looks like this:

.

```
..
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN orderdate < @start 
            THEN 0.00 
        WHEN orderdate >= @end
            THEN total_payment_received
        ELSE 
            CASE DATEPART(MONTH, orderDate)
                WHEN 1
                    THEN 1.54
                WHEN 2 
                    THEN 1.54
                WHEN 3 
                    THEN 1.54
                WHEN 4 
                    THEN 1.54
                WHEN 5
                    THEN 1.54
            END
    END
    )  AS PaymentReceived_LastYear
...
```

Comment: I haven't run this yet but wouldn't this still sum the 1.54 of the months that I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: Um, yeah... I meant that! Unfortunately, that means I didn't read your question well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than edit my original answer (I leave it as a mark of shame), here is a new answer, based on this snippet of your original code.  If you want to use a table to hold the "Monthly Override" values, that would work quite well here - either a temp table or a permanent one. My example includes the use of a permanent table.

First, we set up the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Overrides (
    [Month] char(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    amount decimal(9,2) NOT NULL
    )  

INSERT INTO Overrides ([Month], amount) VALUES
    ('01', 1.54),           -- NOTE: This was new in SQL 2012. If your version is older, 
    ('02', 1.54),           --       use separate INSERT statements
    ('03', 1.54),
    ('04', 1.54),
    ('05', 1.54)
```

Then modify your base code to work like this, making your original query a derived table for the final SELECT

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN GROUPING([month]) = 1 
        THEN 'Totals' 
    ELSE O.[Month]
END AS [Month],
ISNULL(O.amount, PaymentReceived_LastYear) AS PaymentReceived_LastYear,
PaymentReceived_PriorYear  
FROM ( 
    SELECT
        CONVERT(CHAR(2), MONTH(orders.orderdate)) 
        END AS [Month]
    , SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN YEAR(orders.orderdate) = Datepart(yy, Dateadd(mm, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
            THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN MONTH(orders.orderdate) IN (SELECT [Month] FROM Overrides)
                    THEN 0.00
                    ELSE orders.total_payment_received
                END
            ELSE 0.00 
        END
        )   AS PaymentReceived_LastYear
    , SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN YEAR(orders.orderdate) = Datepart(yy, Dateadd(mm, -13, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
            THEN orders.total_payment_received
            ELSE 0.00 
        END
        )   AS PaymentReceived_PriorYear 
    FROM   
        orders 
    GROUP BY   
        MONTH(orders.orderdate)
    ) AS base
LEFT JOIN Overrides AS O
    ON base.[Month] = O.[Month]
WITH ROLLUP
```

With these changes, you should get what you were looking for.